# If $V(I)\cap V(J)=\varnothing$, then $\sqrt{I}+\sqrt{J}=k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

I'm trying to prove it as follows:
\begin{align}
\sqrt{I}+\sqrt{J}&=I(V(I))+I(V(J))\\
&=I(V(I)\cap V(J))\tag{* is this true?}\\
&=I(\varnothing)\\
&=k[x_1,\dots,x_n]
\end{align}

But I'm not sure how to prove the second equality. It might not be true in general. But is it true in this case?

Comment: Presumably you are assuming $k$ is algebraically closed (or defining $V(I)$ to be a subset of $\overline{k}^n$)? (otherwise consider $k=\mathbb R$ and $I=J=(x^2+1)k[x]$)

Comment: @stewbasic Yes. k is algebraically closed.

Comment: Hint: $V(\sqrt{I}+\sqrt{J})\subseteq V(\sqrt{I})=V(I)$.

Comment: @stewbasic It worked. Thank you!